# onSuccess and onFailure doesn't get fired

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webmethod, pagemethods

I have used onSuccess and onFailure in my PageMethod call. However neither of them gets called and the WebMethod doesn't get fired either.

```
alert("1");
PageMethods.LoginUser(onSuccess, onFailure, email, pass);
alert("2");

function onSuccess(val)
{
}
function onFailure()
{
}

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static int LoginUser(string email, string pass)
{
       //Doesn't get fired
}
```

When I remove them and send only the values to the WebMethod, it works:

```
PageMethods.LoginUser(email, pass);
//This fires the Web Method
```

I have enabled PageMethods in my ScriptManager as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `onSuccess` and `onFailure` should follow the page method's arguments, not precede them.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi please explain in detail?

Comment: Well, you should write `PageMethods.LoginUser(email, pass, onSuccess, onFailure);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You PageMethod is looking like this

`PageMethods.LoginUser(onSuccess, onFailure, email, pass);`

And when you call it, it looks like this

```
PageMethods.LoginUser(email, pass);
```

Your arguments should be in the same order as the method.

```
PageMethods.LoginUser(email, pass, onSuccess, onFailure);
```

Comment: Oh i see exactly what édéric Hamidi said